# Tradingview’s Pine: preceding trading day and holidays

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Subtracting the correct amount of milliseconds works if the previous trading day isn’t separated by a holiday:

```
start = input.time(timestamp("2024-02-29T00:00"), "")
start := start - 86400000  // start is now 28 february
```

But this will naturally fail for `start = input.time(timestamp("2024-03-04T00:00"), "")`, which wouldn’t become 1 march.

What is the reliable way of accessing the previous (or following) trading day after a date input for backtesting, taking non-trading days into account?